# Multiple True Cases in Select Case Statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to know how to have Select Case continue running after it encounters first expression that evaluates to true. In the below example, only message box "Z is less than 9" will be triggered. I would like to know how to have code continue so that, in this example, message box "Z is less than 10" will be shown after "Z is less than 9"

```
Sub SelectCaseTrying()
    Dim Z As Integer
    Z = 8
Select Case Z
    Case 5 To 9
        MsgBox "Z is less than 9"
    Case Is < 10
        MsgBox "Z is less than 10"
    Case Is > 15
        MsgBox "Z is greater than 15"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Z is "
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Use separate `If`-statements instead.

Comment: If, however, you only need the last one that's true, you can change the order of the case-statements. The case statements will only check the conditions until it finds a true one, so changing the order will affect which message box gets shown.

Comment: *Would like to know how to have Select Case continue running after it encounters first expression that evaluates to true* - that is exactly the opposite of how `Select...Case` works: think of it as a cleaner way to write `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...ElseIf...ElseIf...` blocks: only 1 branch gets to execute. If more than one condition can be true, then you need separate conditional blocks, and `Select...Case` is the wrong tool for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I would like to know how to have Select Case continue running after it encounters first expression that evaluates to true.*

You can't have that, because as per language specifications, `Case` blocks don't "fall through" in VBA, so if you had this:

```
Select Case Z
    Case Is < 15
        MsgBox "less than 15"
    Case Is < 10
        MsgBox "less than 10"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "greater than or equal to 10"
End Select
```

Then the second `Case` is heuristically unreachable - and a static code analysis tool like [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (disclaimer: I'm a contributor to this open-source project), can warn about that:

[image: Rubberduck code inspections warning about unreachable Case clause]

Think of `Select...Case` as a cleaner way to write `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...ElseIf...ElseIf...` blocks: the conditions should all be mutually exclusive, and only one branch gets to execute.

If you need two or more conditional blocks to run, then you can't use a `Select...Case` because that's not what `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...` does: if you need two or more conditional blocks to run, you need two or more separate conditional blocks (`If...End If`).